# Read from Dataset

Tags: c#

I need to read value of the dataset.
This dataset return many rows. and each rows have single value (Customer_Name)

Comment: question is not enough to give a soluiton. are you looking for ds.Tables["tablename"].Columns["Customer_Name"]

Comment: i think yes, he is looking for that

Comment: your question is not clear enough for me, but you can check these links, i am sure it will help:

http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/

http://www.asp.net/learn/data-videos/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you have one table in dataset and that table has one column you could do it like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string result = row[0].ToString();
        }
```

Or:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables["tablename"].Rows)
        {
            string result = row["columnname"].ToString();
        }
```